# NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{OqtopIzTQmOjjLBzr2G_JA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a problem with spring-data-elasticsearch installing. I tried many ways to fix this but they didnt work. I'm studying course from udemy its 2016-2017 year and i'm using new version of dependencies of spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa. Please help)

**ElasticSearchConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("info.***.resume")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"info.***.resume.search"})
public class ElasticSearchConfig {
    @Value("${elasticsearch.home}")//C:/Users/*username*/IdeaProjects/resume/elastic-search-data
    private String elasticSearchHome;

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws UnknownHostException {
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                .put("path.home", elasticSearchHome)
                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
//            return new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
//                    .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
        client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

**ProfileSearchRepository.java**

```
public interface ProfileSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Profile, Long> {

    Page<Profile> findByObjectiveLikeOrSummaryLike(String objective, String summary, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**ElasticSearchIndexingService.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ElasticSearchIndexingService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSearchIndexingService.class);
    @Value("${index.all.during.startup}")
    private boolean indexAllDuringStartup;

    private final ProfileSearchRepository profileSearchRepository;
    private final ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;
    private final FindProfileService findProfileService;

    @Autowired
    public ElasticSearchIndexingService(ProfileSearchRepository profileSearchRepository, ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations, FindProfileService findProfileService) {
        this.profileSearchRepository = profileSearchRepository;
        this.elasticsearchOperations = elasticsearchOperations;
        this.findProfileService = findProfileService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        if (indexAllDuringStartup) {
            LOGGER.info("Detected index ALL command");
            LOGGER.info("Clear old index");
Line38      elasticsearchOperations.deleteIndex(Profile.class);
            LOGGER.info("Start index of profiles");
            for (Profile p : findProfileService.findAllForIndexing()) {
                profileSearchRepository.save(p);
                LOGGER.info("Successful indexing of profile:{}", p.getUid());
            }
            LOGGER.info("Finish index of profiles");
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("IndexAllDuringStartup is disabled");
        }

    }
}
```

**Profile.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
@Document(indexName = "profile")
public class Profile {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String uid;
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "objective")
    private String objective;
    @Column
    private String summary;
    @Column(name = "birth_day")
    private Date birthDay;
    @Column
    private String city;
    @Column
    private String country;
    @Column
    @JsonIgnore
    private String email;
    @Column
    @JsonIgnore
    private String phone;
    @Column
    private String info;
    @Column(name = "large_photo")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String largePhoto;

    @Column(name = "small_photo")
    private String smallPhoto;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private boolean completed;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(insertable = false)
    private Timestamp created;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Certificate> certificates;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @OrderBy("finishYear DESC, beginYear DESC, id DESC")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Education> educations;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Hobby> hobbies;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Language> languages;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @OrderBy("finishDate DESC ")
    private List<Practice> practices;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @OrderBy("id ASC ")
    private List<Skill> skills;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @OrderBy("finishDate DESC ")
    private List<Course> courses;

    @Embedded
    @JsonIgnore
    private Contacts contacts;
```

**LOG**

```
ERROR ContextLoader Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticSearchIndexingService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{OqtopIzTQmOjjLBzr2G_JA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1728)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{OqtopIzTQmOjjLBzr2G_JA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:352)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:248)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:403)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:391)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1262)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.exists(AbstractClient.java:1286)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.indexExists(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:715)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:732)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:726)
    at info.windigital.resume.search.ElasticSearchIndexingService.postConstruct(ElasticSearchIndexingService.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
    ... 61 more
27-Apr-2020 13:52:09.140 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
27-Apr-2020 13:52:09.141 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/resume] startup failed due to previous errors
27-Apr-2020 13:52:09.206 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [resume] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2020-04-27 01:52:09,227] Artifact resume:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Comment: do you have an elasticsearch node running on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a [deprecated transport client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html) to interact with Elasticsearch, while Elasticsearch officially released high-level java rest-client which is a preferred method for clients to connect with Elasticsearch.

**Transport client is used by nodes in the cluster for communication which will be totally removed in 8.X as mentioned in the same doc:**

> Deprecated in 7.0.0. The TransportClient is deprecated in favour of
>   the Java High Level REST Client and will be removed in Elasticsearch
>   8.0. The migration guide describes all the steps needed to migrate.

**You should create a preferred and official high-level java client as shown below:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;@Configuration
static class Config {

  @Bean
  RestHighLevelClient client() {

    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder() 
      .connectedTo("localhost:9200", "localhost:9201")
      .build();

    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();                  
  }
}
```

Once created you can simply autowired this `client` and use it for all the operations of Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you for helping. And so what should i do in this case? How to use highLevelClient

Comment: @DenisDeniben, I mentioned the code by which you can create a rest high level client in sping-data, just use this code to create a client and you should be able to make it work

Comment: @DenisDeniben pls follow this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest to create client and autowire it

Comment: it's so hard. I need use this  **elasticsearchOperations.deleteIndex(Profile.class);** but when i autowire  RestHighLevelClient or highLevelClient.lowLevelClient();    i dont see method deleteIndex().... help me)

Comment: You should read about the concept of Spring Data Elasticsearch (templates and repositories). The client is just the connection to the underlying Elasticsearch cluster. Normally when using Spring Data Elasticsearch there is no need to directly use the client at all.

Comment: @DenisDeniben did you get a chance to go through my last comment ?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I upvoted you, but first downvote wasn't mine)

Comment: @DenisDeniben oh ok, don't know who did it :(. without giving reason. anyway thanks :)